# how to use std::generate_canonical to generate random number in range [0,1)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am running into an issue when trying to use `std::generate_canonical`. From my reading at [cpp-reference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/generate_canonical), I expect `std::generate_canonical` to generate numbers in the range [0,1).
However, on an up-to-date MSVC 2012 (CTP not installed), `std::generate_canonical` generates numbers that are all of the order 10^28 (see below). Indeed, [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462289.aspx) does not mention the range in which `std::generate_canonical` generates numbers.

Does Microsoft not comply with the standard here? Or is the standard deficient in that it is vague about `std::generate_canonical`'s behavior? In the second case, how would I write code to generate a random floating point number in the range [0,1)?

Please consider the below example code for my attempt at using `std::generate_canonical`.

```
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::random_device rd;
    // seed with true source of randomness
    std::mt19937 _rng_generator(rd());

    for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << std::generate_canonical<double,std::numeric_limits<double>::digits>(_rng_generator) << ' ';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example of the output I get:
    `4.85267e+028 2.76741e+028 3.17392e+028 5.84136e+028 1.0037e+028 4.87202e+028 2.53834e+028 4.233e+028 6.43922e+028 2.30694e+028`

**Update:**
I have previously reported the bug to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811611/std-generate-canonical-does-not-generate-random-number-in-range-0-1). The bug has now been fixed and the fix will be included in MSVC 2014 RTM.

Comment: I compiled this in Linux with G++ 4.8 and it produced 10 random numbers in the range [0,1).  I don't know what Microsoft is doing to you.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 also generates the bogus values.  [uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) would probably work for what you need.

Comment: @RetiredNinja. Indeed, using [uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) will be the solution for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 26.5.7.2 Function template generate_canonical [rand.util.canonical]
>
> Each function instantiated from the template described in this section
>   26.5.7.2 maps the result of one or more invocations of a supplied uniform random number generator `g` to one member of the specified
>   `RealType` such that, if the values `g`<sub>i</sub> produced by `g` are uniformly
>   distributed, the instantiation's results `tj`, 0 ≤ `tj` < 1, are
>   distributed as uniformly as possible as specified below.
>
> ```
> template<class RealType, size_t bits, class URNG> 
> RealType generate_canonical(URNG& g);
> ```

Also, Standard describes, that this function returns [image: s/rk], where
[image: S]
[image: R]

So, this function should return a value from zero to one. I think, Microsoft implementation is wrong here.

Comment: thanks, reported bug in [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811611/std-generate-canonical-does-not-generate-random-number-in-range-0-1#)

Answer (score 1):

The [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/generate_canonical) that you refer to currently says:

"Some existing implementations have a bug where they may occasionally return 1.0 if RealType is float GCC #63176 LLVM #18767. This is LWG issue 2524"

According to the [issue](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2524), "The problem is that the standard specifies the implementation, and the implementation doesn't work."

The issue was opened on 2015-08-20, a couple of years after you posted this question.

Answer (score -4):

Here is the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462289.aspx

Here's the corresponding prototype:

```
template<class RealType,
    size_t bits,
    class Engine>
    RealType generate_canonical(Engine& gen);
```

And here is a complete example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982398.aspx

```
// cl.exe /EHsc /nologo /W4 /MTd
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename C> void print(const C& c) {
    for (const auto& e : c) {
        cout << e << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void test(unsigned int seed) {
    cout << "Seed: " << seed << endl;

    mt19937 engine(seed);

    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(-3, 5);

    vector<int> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        v.push_back(dist(engine));
    }

    cout << "Randomized vector: ";
    print(v);

    array<string, 26> arr = { { "H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F",
        "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca", "Sc",
        "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe" } };

    shuffle(arr.begin(), arr.end(), engine);

    cout << "Randomized array: ";
    print(arr);
}

int main() {
    cout << "--" << endl;

    test(12345);

    cout << "--" << endl;

    random_device rd;

    test(rd());
}
```

Comment: That's the link that was given in the original question.  That doesn't answer why MSVC++ isn't producing values in the expected range [0,1).

Comment: Ok, I see your edit with an elaborate example that still doesn't address why `generate_canonical` isn't producing the expected results.  Your example doesn't even _use_ `generate_canonical`. Are you reading the same question I am?